# Noise Texture Stretching on Side of Cube

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm attempting to create a simple resized cube with a noise texture on all six sides.  The cube is just a default cube that is scaled down in the Z axis so it appears very short.

No matter what version of Blender I use, the top of the cube works completely fine, showing the noise texture as usual, but the sides of the cube appear like this (this screenshot is from Blender 2.7, but my main computer does the exact same on Blender 2.8):

[image: Image with stretched sides and correct top]

Things I've already tried:
 - I've made sure that the UV unwrap is correctly scaled to the scale and rotation.

- I've tried putting a texture on it, the texture lines up properly and doesn't stretch: [image: Correct texturing]
- I've tried converting the noise texture to a bump map and a normal map, it doesn't change the result.
- I've tried two different versions of Blender and 2 different machines

While I'm sure there is something very simple going on here that I'm missing because I'm inexperienced, I'm stuck and can't find any information on my errors.

Extra Images:
 - UV Unwrap: [image: Unwrap of cube]
 - Basic Node Setup: [image: Node Setup]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: @Timaroberts i've already applied all the transforms, that was one of the first things I tried.  I'm assuming the only way to apply transforms is by doing Ctrl+A and then applying rotation and scale, if there's something else needed then I'll do it.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You need to connect your UV map.**

Image textures use generated coordinates by default - this makes your texture stretched.
Noise texture works fine with generated coordinates, so it looks okay in your case.

**Solution:**
1) Add a Texture coordinate node and a Mapping node.
2) Connect your UV map output.
3) Done

[image]

**Comparison between different variants**
Left - properly connected UV map
Center - texture without UV map connected (clearly distorted)
Right - Procedural textures work just fine

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks especially for explaining why it worked, that'll help me with similar problems in the future.

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your other projects :).